# How to manage execute user privileges in CPanel?

Tags: mysql, privileges, cpanel

I created a User in my CPanel with **All Privileges**. But unfortunately my CPanel did not allow me to set the **Execute** Privilege. It shows the success report but when I again check it did not set this privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact your Hosting Provider. This is a CPanel error. Your Hosting Provider will solve that issue.

Comment: Many many thanks for helping me. I was stuck. +1 Rep for you.